# Как сдвинуть все ID если пользователь захочет удалить ряд из SQLite в JavaFX?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, scene-builder

Пишу приложение на JavaFX и Scene builder. В качестве базы данных - SQLite.

В качестве редактирования и просмотра баз данных - DB Browser

Я хочу добавлять записи из текстовых полей textAria в колонки SQLite при клике на кнопку "Add" и удалять записи при клике на кнопку "Delete"

Кнопки отрабатывают нормально, но проблема в том, что если я удалю какой нибудь ряд из SQlite все остальные ряды не сдвигаются, и при добавлении новой записи новый ряд имеет новый ID, а не принимает удаленный ID

Удаление и добавление происходит у меня из combobox. Сombobox отображает все ID в колонке из SQLite

[image: Combobox]

Такое ощущение,что между ID в базе данных есть пустые ID, которые не отображаются.

Я хочу,чтобы все ID сдвигались при добавлении или удалении записей из БД

**Как сделать,чтобы все номера в колонке ID в SQLite сдвигались автоматически?**

Текущая ситуация:

[image: SQLite]

[image: Column ID]

Результат, который хочу достичь:

[image: SQlite 2]

**Класс, где я добавляю номера из колонки ID(SQLite) в Observable list:**

```
    package src.card;

   import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
   import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Cards {

  PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();

  final ObservableList<String> OBS = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   Connection connection;
   PreparedStatement pst = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   public Cards() {
    try {
  this.connection = DbConnection.getConnection();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

if (this.connection == null) {
  System.out.println("connection is not successful!");
  System.exit(1);
    }

  }

  public Connection getConnection() {return connection;}

  public void setConnection(Connection connection) {this.connection = 
connection;}



  public ObservableList getOBS() {return OBS;}


  //add ID of cards to combobox
  void fillCombobox() {
    try {
  pst = getConnection().prepareStatement(pq.getSqlSelectID());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();

  while (rs.next()) {
    getOBS().add(rs.getString("ID"));
  }

  pst.close();
  rs.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }


   //check if database is connected
   public boolean isDbConnected() {
    return this.connection != null;
  }

}
```

**Класс, в котором находятся SQlite запросы:**

```
package src.card;

 public class PersistentQueries {

 private String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Cards(question, answer) VALUES 
 (?,?)";
 private String sqlSelectID = "SELECT ID FROM Cards";
 private String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE ID = ?";
 private String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM Cards WHERE ID = ?";


 public String getSqlInsert() {
   return sqlInsert;
  }

 public void setSqlInsert(String sqlInsert) {
  this.sqlInsert = sqlInsert;
  }


 public String getSqlSelectID() {
return sqlSelectID;
 }

 public void setSqlSelectID(String sqlSelectID) {
this.sqlSelectID = sqlSelectID;
 }

 public String getSqlSelect() {
  return sqlSelect;
}

public void setSqlSelect(String sqlSelect) {
this.sqlSelect = sqlSelect;
}

 public String getSqlDelete() {
return sqlDelete;
}

 public void setSqlDelete(String sqlSelect) {
this.sqlDelete = sqlSelect;
  }
}
```

**Контроллер, с методами для добавления или удаления ID:**

```
package src.card;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class QuestController implements Initializable {

 @FXML private TextArea ta_questText, ta_answerText;
 @FXML private Label questId, error;
 @FXML private ComboBox<String> combobox_question;

  Cards cards = new Cards();
  PersistentQueries pq = new PersistentQueries();

  ResultSet rs = null;
  PreparedStatement pst = null;


  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


//register QuestController in  Context Class
Context.getInstance().setQuestController(this);

cards.fillCombobox();
combobox_question.setItems(cards.getOBS());

  }

  //adding cards to database, update combobox and clear label text
  @FXML
  void addCard(ActionEvent event) {

if (ta_questText.getText().equals("") || ta_answerText.getText().equals("")) {
  error.setText("All fields are required!");
} else {
  try {

    error.setText("");
    Connection conn = DbConnection.getConnection();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlInsert());
    pst.setString(1, this.ta_questText.getText());
    pst.setString(2, this.ta_answerText.getText());
    pst.execute();

    pst = conn.prepareStatement(pq.getSqlSelectID());
    rs = pst.executeQuery();

    ta_questText.clear();
    ta_answerText.clear();
    cards.getOBS().clear();
    questId.setText("");

    cards.fillCombobox();

    pst.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();


  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
   }

 }

 @FXML
 void deleteID(ActionEvent event) {

try {

  pst = cards.getConnection().prepareStatement(pq.getSqlDelete());
  pst.setString(1, (String) 
  combobox_question.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
  pst.execute();

  pst.close();
  rs.close();
  cards.getConnection().close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

}

  //apply id to label and set text to TextArias from SQLite
  @FXML
  void idList(ActionEvent event) {

questId.setText(combobox_question.getValue() + ".");


try {
  pst = cards.getConnection().prepareStatement(pq.getSqlSelect());
  pst.setString(1, (String) 
 combobox_question.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
  rs = pst.executeQuery();
  while (rs.next()) {

    ta_questText.setText(rs.getString("question"));
    ta_answerText.setText(rs.getString("answer"));
  }

  pst.close();
  rs.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: Вся суть идентификаторов в том, что они никогда не меняются.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да, я это понимаю, но можно ли этого как-то избежать? а то мой друг захочет посмотреть в combobox все номера, а там если будет что-то типа 1, 4, ,25, 52. Спросит че за херня) нужно сделать чтобы в combobox отображалось все по порядку. Сейчас же я даже не знаю как мне вернуть эти пустые id обратно, цифры перескакивают через эти удаленные при добавлении

Comment: возможно ли например получить вместо колонки ID в SQLite , id ряда самого SQlite? там то уже точно все по порядку идет

Comment: Нет, не по порядку. Большинство СУБД, включая SQLite, хранят данные в произвольном порядке. И выбирают их тоже в произвольном, если не задано правило сортировки.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а можно ли в каком-либо классе, например в контроллер задать  сортировку SQLite этих ID по порядку?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev а то,что у меня rowid каждого ряда находится по порядку это особенность DB Browser?

Comment: rowid есть только в больших субд типа оракла, у sqlite rowid используется только для автоинкремента идентификаторов, из него можно узнать только какой будет использован следующий идентификатор для таблицы. Даже, если вы вручную сдвините все номера, то при добавлении новой строки, идентификатор будет взят из этого rowid, а не то что вы хотите. используйте собственное поле и меняйте в нем значение, если хотите, что бы эти числа были по порядку.

Comment: мне хотя бы узнать теперь как удалить пустые номера из колонки ID, заново создавать таблицу и добавлять ID?

Comment: С какой целью отображать идентификаторы в ComboBox? Можно сделать еще одно поле, например, question_num, где хранить номера вопросов. Как правило, из таких таблиц редко удаляются записи, чаще записи метят как удаленные, чтоб их отсекать во время запроса и не отображать в интерфейсе, но чтоб их можно было посмотреть в случае необходимости. Часто записи связаны с другими записями в др. таблицах, и при удалении будут образовываться битые ссылки... Все, конечно, зависит от постановки.

Comment: @Z.John  так вот ID это и есть номера вопросов, то есть question_num как  вы написали. Этот ID (номер  вопроса с ответом) отображается в combobox, при клике на который в программе можно выбрать ID вопроса с ответом, и удалить или редактировать при желании

Comment: мне не важно, что ID вопроса с ответа будет меняться при удалении/добавлении, мне главное чтобы в combobox был отображены порядковые номера всех  вопросов с ответами. Пусть даже в браузере (DB Browser) SQlite будут не порядковые ID хотя тут тоже может возникнуть путаница, если в combobox будет id 25 вопроса и ответа, а в таблице SQlite этот же ID будет иметь другой номер

Comment: Какой примерно объем вопров ожидается

Comment: @Z.John вообще имеется 8 категорий с карточками с вопросами и ответами и одна категория для простого текста. В каждой категории 100 вопросов и ответов к ним. ТО есть я планировал сделать 8 таблиц для вопросных карточек   и одну таблицу для НЕ вопросных. Получается в каждой таблице 100 рядов

Comment: думаю правильней сделать две таблицы: таблица категорий и таблица с вопросами и ответами

Comment: @Z.John а как буут выглядеть колонки с таблице с категориями? вообще в дальнейшем мне нужно будет сделать так,чтобы на главном экране при  клике на категорию появлялась карточка с вопросом и ответом на задней стороне именно из выбранной категории. Типо как в ТВ программе "Своя игра"

Comment: добавил в ответ пример скриптов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот набросал скрипты для таблиц (только в MySql)

```
CREATE TABLE `example_category` (
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `active` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `category_name_UNIQUE` (`category_name` ASC));

CREATE TABLE `example_questions` (
  `qurestion_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_num` INT NOT NULL,
  `question_text` VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
  `question_answer` VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `active` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`qurestion_id`),
  INDEX `FK_QUESTION_CATEGORY_idx` (`category_id` ASC),
  INDEX `UK_NUM_CATEGORY` (`category_id` ASC, `question_num` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_QUESTION_CATEGORY`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`)
    REFERENCES `example_category` (`category_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: я никогда не работал с базами данных. Эти запросы чем-то отличаются от SQLite?

Comment: скорей всего отличия если и есть, то небольшие, точнее пока сказать не могу давно с SQLite работать не приходилось. разница может быть в кавычках в наименованиях таблиц и полей, и в типах полей

Comment: спасибо за ответы!